# Cannot convert non-arrow function to a function expression. React/Preact build fail

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, babeljs, preact

I am building a React app well technically preact but on the build it fails on the current code:

This is what the "helper class" looks like:

```
class DuplicateChecker {

  hasDuplicates = async () => {
     const checkFirstPage = await this.isDuplicateFoundOnFirst();
...etc
```

It is imported to a component and used to help checking for stuff

And this is the error output

```
Cannot convert non-arrow function to a function expression.
  14 |   }
  15 |
> 16 |   hasDuplicates = async () => {
     |                      ^
  17 |     const checkFirstPage = await this.isDuplicateFoundOnFirst();
  18 |
```

My .babelrc looks as following:

```
{
    "presets": [
        "preact-cli/babel"
    ],
    "plugins": [
        "@quickbaseoss/babel-plugin-styled-components-css-namespace",
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
        "@babel/plugin-transform-arrow-functions",
        "babel-plugin-styled-components"
    ]
}
```

And still once i run the build it fails, not sure on why since it should compile the code properly

Comment: Did you try `hasDuplicates = async function () {`?

Comment: or `const hasDuplicates = async () => {}`

Comment: ive forgotten to metion that it is a class. Editing the file as of right now

Comment: edited the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solved, here is the solution:**

Thanks to https://github.com/rschristian

The issue was within the *.babelrc* file, so i've deleted it and added my babel plugins within **preact.config.js** as followed:

```
export default (config, env, helpers) => {
    const { rule } = helpers.getLoadersByName(config, 'babel')[0];
    const babelConfig = rule.options;

    babelConfig.plugins.push(
        '@quickbaseoss/babel-plugin-styled-components-css-namespace',
        'babel-plugin-styled-components'
    );
}
```

After this change the build works fine with original syntax.

Hope this helps anyone

Answer (score 0):

This syntax should work:

[TS Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&ssl=14&ssc=6&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYGwhgzhAEAiCuAHEBLYYAuBTAwgCy2AGssAnaAbwChppIBPAO2Gj0gWTUyxgAoBKSjVrQA9KOjIwwLHgD2IACZlowOcoBcw2qSwZ4pRtACymPADpSYRorkBbAdAA80AAzmArAG5hAXyr+VFTi0ACqEFhavAzM0I4AvAB8QrRqjBAY0Ios8dCMWADucEio6Nj4hCSkAj6pcumZiiVc2BAAYnLwNtC5YAVgKI3A5mwQHKXcEDXCaRAKWOYgcgDmvE2cZTwdXYr8Pr7800A)

```ts
class DuplicateChecker {
  async hasDuplicates () {
    // placeholder code:
    return Math.random() < 0.5;
  }
}


// Use:
(async () => {
  const dc = new DuplicateChecker();
  const duplicatesFound = await dc.hasDuplicates();
  console.log(duplicatesFound);
})();
```

Or, since it's not TypeScript (according to your question), you can just assign it in the constructor, like this:

```js
class DuplicateChecker {
  constructor () {
    this.hasDuplicates = async () => {
      // placeholder code:
      return Math.random() < 0.5;
    };
  }
}
```

Edit: Another syntax:

```js
class DuplicateChecker {
  hasDuplicates = async function () {
    // placeholder code:
    return Math.random() < 0.5;
  };
}
```

Comment: shouldn't babel take care of that?

Comment: I have no idea how your build tools are setup or what rules you have configured for transformations of your source code. I'm just offering you a suggested valid syntax for your method.

Comment: Did one of those syntaxes solve the problem?

Comment: unfortunately not :/

Comment: @AlbertKarter I added one more syntax (the one from [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70271329/cannot-convert-non-arrow-function-to-a-function-expression-react-preact-build-f/70271685?noredirect=1#comment124220796_70271329)) at the end of my answer. Does it work for you?